# SQL query using temp tables is duplicating results for each case statement used

Tags: sql-server, case, temp-tables

I need to be able to pull those students currently enrolled, then define smaller sub-terms, status, and a label based on the first category they fall into. Category- Athlete,Dual Credit,Fine arts,Health Professions,CTE,Campus 1,Campus 2,Campus 3,Online,Campus 4,No assignment

Much of the information I need is in several tables and the primary key's are labeled differently in all of the tables. I created three temp tables, one for the students and the other two for the remaining pieces of information. Then I joined all three tables and have case statements to look over the sub term and grouping hierarchy that we want to use.

The query is able to pull everything and the case statements work, the issue is that they records are duplicated when they fall into more than one category. I tried putting the case statements in the relevant temp table and then in the final query where all three tables are joined but nothing has worked.

Originally I was using Tableau and able to do everything, but the same problem arose when looking at one or multiple terms, counts were being duplicated when students were in more than one category.

Ex-Student is taking a 16 week class and two 8 week classes. She is a Fine arts students and in the CTE program, she would fall in to the Fine arts category and have that title for each of the sub terms.

[Example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghlBR.png) --> Distinct ID 21/SP CTE

[Example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KaS16.png) --> Distinct ID 21/SP Online

This is the final query used at the end, it joins the three tables together on the #ENROLL table where the original temp table is used to query the students we need and get a distinct list.

```
SELECT DISTINCT E.STUDENT_ID AS  "S_ID",
            --#PROG.PROGRAM,
            #SPECIAL.[NEW/RETURNER],
          CASE 
          WHEN  ENROLL_START_DATE = '01/19/2021' AND E.ENROLL_END_DATE = '05/11/2021' THEN '21/SP 16W'
          WHEN  [ENROLL_START_DATE] = '01/19/2021' AND ENROLL_END_DATE = '03/17/2021' THEN '21/SP 8W1'
          WHEN  [ENROLL_START_DATE] = '03/22/2021' AND ENROLL_END_DATE = '05/11/2021' THEN '21/SP 8W2'
          WHEN  [ENROLL_START_DATE] = '05/17/2021' AND ENROLL_END_DATE = '06/03/2021' THEN '21/SP MM'
          WHEN  [ENROLL_START_DATE] = '06/07/2021' AND ENROLL_END_DATE = '07/12/2021' THEN '21/S1 6W1'
          WHEN  [ENROLL_START_DATE] = '06/07/2021' AND ENROLL_END_DATE = '08/16/2021' THEN '21/S1 12W'
          WHEN  [ENROLL_START_DATE] = '07/13/2021' AND ENROLL_END_DATE = '08/16/2021' THEN '21/S2 6W2'
          WHEN  [ENROLL_START_DATE] = '08/23/2021' AND ENROLL_END_DATE = '12/11/2021' THEN '21/FA 16W'
          WHEN  [ENROLL_START_DATE] = '08/23/2021' AND ENROLL_END_DATE= '10/13/2021' THEN '21/FA 8W1'
          WHEN  [ENROLL_START_DATE] = '10/18/2021' AND ENROLL_END_DATE = '12/11/2021' THEN '21/FA 8W2'
          --ELSE ' '
          END AS [SUB TERM],
          CASE 
          WHEN #SPECIAL.GROUPING = 'ATHLETE' THEN 'ATHLETE'
          WHEN DC.DC_RESTRICTION = 'CCHS' THEN 'DC'
          WHEN #SPECIAL.GROUPING = 'FA' THEN 'FA'
          WHEN #PROG.PROGRAM = 'HP' THEN 'HP'
          WHEN #PROG.PROGRAM = 'CTE' THEN 'CTE'
          WHEN #SPECIAL.GROUPING = 'MEX' THEN 'MEXIA CAMPUS'
          WHEN #SPECIAL.GROUPING = 'WAX' THEN 'WAXAHACHIE CAMPUS'
          WHEN #SPECIAL.GROUPING = 'MID' THEN 'MIDLOTHIAN CAMPUS'
          WHEN #SPECIAL.GROUPING = 'ITN' THEN 'ONLINE'
          WHEN #SPECIAL.GROUPING = 'CC'  THEN 'CORSICANA CAMPUS'
          ELSE '  '
          END AS 'NEW GROUP' 
              
FROM #ENROLL E
LEFT JOIN #SPECIAL ON #SPECIAL.N05_STTR_STUDENT = E.STUDENT_ID 
LEFT JOIN #PROG ON #PROG.N05_PRGM_STUDENT = E.STUDENT_ID
LEFT JOIN [coll18_prod].[dbo].N05_DUAL_CREDIT DC ON DC_ID = E.STUDENT_ID
ORDER BY S_ID
```

Update:
I created a rank for each category per term.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#RANK') is not null
       DROP TABLE #RANK 
       SELECT *,

       CASE
          WHEN #ENROLL_1.[NEW GROUP] LIKE 'ATHLETE' THEN 1
          WHEN #ENROLL_1.[NEW GROUP] LIKE 'DC' THEN 2
          WHEN #ENROLL_1.[NEW GROUP] LIKE 'FA' THEN 3
          WHEN #ENROLL_1.[NEW GROUP] LIKE 'HP' THEN 4
          WHEN #ENROLL_1.[NEW GROUP] LIKE 'CTE' THEN 5
          WHEN #ENROLL_1.[NEW GROUP] LIKE 'MEXIA CAMPUS' THEN 6
          WHEN #ENROLL_1.[NEW GROUP] LIKE 'WAXAHACHIE CAMPUS' THEN 7
          WHEN #ENROLL_1.[NEW GROUP] LIKE 'MIDLOTHIAN CAMPUS' THEN 8
          WHEN #ENROLL_1.[NEW GROUP] LIKE 'ONLINE' THEN 9
          WHEN #ENROLL_1.[NEW GROUP] LIKE 'CORSICANA CAMPUS'  THEN 10
          WHEN #ENROLL_1.[NEW GROUP] LIKE '  '  THEN 11
          ELSE '  '
          END AS [RANK],
          CASE 
          WHEN  #ENROLL_1.[SUB TERM] LIKE '21/SP 16W' THEN '21/SP 16W'
          WHEN  #ENROLL_1.[SUB TERM] LIKE '21/SP 8W1' THEN  '21/SP 8W1'
          WHEN  #ENROLL_1.[SUB TERM] LIKE '21/SP 8W2' THEN  '21/SP 8W2'
          WHEN  #ENROLL_1.[SUB TERM] LIKE '21/SP MM' THEN  '21/SP MM' 
          WHEN  #ENROLL_1.[SUB TERM] LIKE '21/S1 6W1' THEN  '21/S1 6W1' 
          WHEN  #ENROLL_1.[SUB TERM] LIKE '21/S1 12W' THEN '21/S1 12W'
          WHEN  #ENROLL_1.[SUB TERM] LIKE '21/S2 6W2' THEN '21/S2 6W2' 
          WHEN  #ENROLL_1.[SUB TERM] LIKE '21/FA 16W' THEN '21/FA 16W'  
          WHEN  #ENROLL_1.[SUB TERM] LIKE '21/FA 8W1' THEN '21/FA 8W1'  
          WHEN  #ENROLL_1.[SUB TERM] LIKE '21/FA 8W2' THEN '21/FA 8W2'
          ELSE ' '
          END AS [S_TERM]

       INTO #RANK
       FROM #ENROLL_1
SELECT DISTINCT #RANK.S_ID,#RANK.[NEW/RETURNER],#RANK.S_TERM,#RANK.[NEW GROUP],MIN(#RANK.[RANK])  FROM #RANK
WHERE #RANK.S_ID =  '0011339'
AND #RANK.[NEW GROUP] <> ' '
GROUP BY #RANK.S_ID,#RANK.[NEW/RETURNER],#RANK.S_TERM,#RANK.[NEW GROUP],#RANK.[RANK]
ORDER BY S_ID
```

The results are close, but it pulls multiple values.  Example is in the picture
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WqQXc.png)

Comment: If the issue is that students fall into more than one category, then you need to determine which category takes priority to only return that row.

Comment: That sounds perfect, how/when do I do that? Is that a specific function do achieve this? Then only way I cant think of is to create a INSERT INTO from the CREATE VIEW I am working with

Comment: I won't be able to tell you that, only you know your data. But I wonder if you're misunderstanding the principle of what makes a row unique. In looking at the second picture, you have rows all for the same ID (0011339), but the other columns provide more detail for each row to be unique. So you have several rows with RETURNER and NEW, but the next column has values like 21/SP 16W and 21/S1 6W1. These different values, despite the other values being the same, make these rows different which is why they're both showing as a "duplicate".